# Enumerate all items to find those that match a complex condition

Tags: php, design-patterns

Currently, I have a big `for..loop` with many `if..else` inside the loop. I just wonder is there any design pattern or other approach to reduce the long code inside the `for..loop`. Thank in advance.

```
foreach ($workingTimes as $hour => $minutes) {
    foreach ($minutes as $shift) {
        $isBookable = $this->isBookabe($hour, $shift);

        if(!$isBookabe) {
            continue;
        }

        $isNotEnoughEmployee = $this->checkEmployees($hours, $shift);

        if(!$isNotEnoughEmployee) {
            continue;
        }

        $isNotEnoughResources = $this->checkResources($hour, $shift);

        if(!$isBookabe) {
            continue;
        }

        $isNotEnoughRooms = $this->checkRooms($hour, $shift);

        if(!$isNotEnoughRooms) {
            continue;
        }

        $formatted = sprintf("%s-%s", $hour, $shift);
        $timetable[$formatted] = 'Bookable';
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a bug there caused by copying and pasting things. Can you spot it?

Comment: Actually, what you have here shouldn't even run. Please at least make sure your code works well before posting it here.

Answer (score 2):

You *can't* reduce code you wrote because each condition has to be checked and you're already using variables to clarify your intent. What you *can* do is to move all that code out of your loop, reading that code in future you won't need to scroll over all those `if`s:

```
foreach ($workingTimes as $hour => $minutes) {
    foreach ($minutes as $shift) {
        if (!canBookRoom($hour, $shift))
            continue;

        $formatted = sprintf("%s-%s", $hour, $shift);
        $timetable[$formatted] = 'Bookable';
    }
}

...

function canBookRoom($hour, $minute) {
    if (!isThereAvailableRoom($hour, $minute))
        return false;

    return areThereAvailableResources($hour, $minute);
}

function isThereAvailableRoom($hour, $minute) {
    if (!$this->isBookable($hours, $shift))
        return false;

    return $this->checkRooms($hour, $shift);
}

function areThereAvailableResources($hour, $minute) {
    if (!$this->checkEmployees($hour, $shift))
        return false;

    return $this->checkResources($hour, $shift);
}
```

**What has been done**

- Reading your loop you're not really interested in all details about availability, there you just need to know if it's bookable or not. Pulling out a function for that makes your code easier to parse and your intent explicit. If/when you'll be interested in that details you may browse to `canBookRoom()` function.
- `canBookRoom()` function itself explicitly split booking availability in two logic *domains*: room availability and resources availability. Each one has its own function.
- `areThereAvailableResources()` unifies *resources*, from a higher level point of view both humans and materials are resources you can *count*.
- Your local variables has been dropped, if each function name is self descriptive then you don't need them.

**What should be done**

- Your loop is still doing many things: it searches for a bookable room inside a time range and if it finds an available time then it marks that range as *bookable*.

At least *something* should be done in a separate function. Here you have two options for your hypothetical `buildTimetableForAllBookableRooms()` function: refactor out function to fill timetable or add one function `findAllBookableRooms()` which returns all available time frames when there is a bookable room plus another function `formatTimetableForBookableRoom()` to perform booking, called in a foreach loop.

```
function findAllBookableRooms() {
    foreach ($workingTimes as $hour => $minutes) {
        foreach ($minutes as $shift) {
            if (canBookRoom($hour, $shift))
                yield sprintf("%s-%s", $hour, $shift);
        }
    }
}

function formatTimetableForBookableRoom() {
    foreach (findAllBookableRooms() as $bookableTimeFrame) {
        $timetable[$bookableTimeFrame] = 'Bookable';
    }
}
```

Here I used generator syntax but you may also return an array. Note that `findAllBookableRooms()` may also return unformatted value using `yeld array($hour, $shift);`.

- Wherever it will be your $formatted variable has a poor name. It should describe what it contains otherwise you may simply drop it).
- Another thing to do (but I don't have enough context) is to rename `isBookable()` and `checkRooms()` functions, from name alone it's not clear what they're actually doing and why/how they're different. Note I renamed `isBookabe()` to `isBookable()`, I suppose it's just a typo.

Answer (score -1):

**Combine assignment with control statement evaluation**

Here's how you can reduce the size of your code slightly, but you cannot reduce control statements in a `for loop` where the whole idea is to evaluate the logic for each of those `for loop` items, as it seems to be here.

```
foreach ($workingTimes as $hour => $minutes) {
    foreach ($minutes as $shift) {
        if(!$isBookable = $this->isBookabe($hour, $shift)) continue;

        if(!$isNotEnoughEmployee = $this->checkEmployees($hours, $shift) continue;

... and so on ...

        $formatted = sprintf("%s-%s", $hour, $shift);
        $timetable[$formatted] = 'Bookable';
    }
}
```

**Shorter variable names**

Also it seems like all your variable names are a bit longer than they need to be. For example, why not `$bookable` rather than `$isBookable` and `$notEnoughEmployees` rather than `$isNotEnoughEmployees`? The `is` at the start of every variable name does not add information.

**Single for loop**

You might consider generating an `array` of all possible times with hours and minutes combined rather than doing a double `for loop`. This way in future if you want to limit certain combinations (for example you can have 17:30 but not 18:30) this would be easier to accomplish.

**Use encapsulation and functions**

I entirely agree with @AdrianoRepetti's commends about better encapsulation and use of functions to signal to code readers (including your future self) what your code is really trying to do.